# Move files to external hard drive rather than copy

Tags: windows-10, external-hard-drive

I regularly move files from my desktop (C:) to my external hard drive (D:). However, when I drag files into my D: drive it *copies* it instead of *moving* it. Is there a way to change this?

**Some background info:**

-My C: is a SSD

-My D: is a NTFS formatted external HDD

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right click and Hold on the files/folders you want to move.
Drag while holding.
When you release you will be given the option to copy or move.

Answer (score 4):

This is the default behavior of D&D on Windows Explorer, it will move on the same disk and copy between different disks.

You can specifically request move by holding down the `Shift` key and request copy when you press `Ctrl` while dragging (with the left mouse button). Similar `Alt` can be used to create links.

If you use instead the right mouse button for dragging it will actually ask you with a pop-up menu, so you do not have to remember the modifier keys.